# C++ function called before constructor cases crash due to uninitialized members

Tags: c++

I have this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    void printB() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
        cout << mModuleName << endl;
    }
    void setModuleName() {
        mModuleName = "BBBBBBB";
    }

private:
    string mModuleName;
};

class A {
public:
    void printA() {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
        b.printB();
    }
    B b;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    cout << " START " << endl;

    std::shared_ptr<A> a;

    a->printA();

    a = std::make_shared<A>();

    cout << " END " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/development$ ./a.out
 START
printA
printB
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This obviously crashes when reaching to line where he tries to access mModuleName. I can fix it by moving printA() after make_shared line but I would like more robust solution to prevent SIGSEGV. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no fix, this isn't a real problem. You are dereferencing a null pointer which is fundamentally against the rules of c++. Trying to fix that isn't plausible in c++.

Comment: *Any suggestions?* **Always** initialize the variable when you declare it.  You do that and you can't have a problem with using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: What's your purpose? As it stands this question makes no sense since I don't see your real requirement. Requesting the ability to dereference a null pointer is not your real problem.

Comment: You are right @Jack. What I would like to be able to do is something like this

`if (mModuleName) cout << mModuleName << endl;`

but this is not possible in C++

Comment: @tomasz: is mModuleName specific of a type or specific of an instance?

Comment: @Jack i would say it is specific to an instance. Each instance of class B should have different mModuleName value.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an actual problem, you're simply doing something that is obviously going to crash because you are dereferencing a null pointer.

You can do this as an alternative and call `make_shared` in the same line you declare the object.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->printA();
    return 0;
}
```

There is no real reason to split up the object declaration and initialization in this case.

Answer (score -1):

> I can fix it by moving printA() after make_shared line but I would like more robust solution to prevent SIGSEGV. Any suggestions?

One possible method is to use a non-member function.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   void print(A* aptr)
   {
      if ( aptr != nullptr )
      {
         aptr->printA();
      }
   }
}
```

and in `main` use

```
MyApp::print(a);
```